# Why does `rm -rf`` silently fail?

Tags: linux, bash, rm, recursive, dir

[EDIT]
Please don't waste your time reading my question below. It turns out my colleague is an idiot.. :)

On my server I'm trying to remove a folder and all its subfolders with the usual `rm -rf dirname`, but it silently fails:

```
kramer65@vps1:~$ ls -l
total 24
drwxrwxr-x  2 kramer65 kramer65 4096 Jul 11 22:00 backups
drwxrwxr-x  2 kramer65 kramer65 4096 Jul 17 17:37 bin
drwxrwxr-x  3 kramer65 kramer65 4096 Sep  1 11:11 cxs
kramer65@vps1:~$ rm -rf cxs/
kramer65@vps1:~$ ls
backups  bin  cxs
kramer65@vps1:~$ sudo rm -rf cxs/
kramer65@vps1:~$ ls
backups  bin  cxs
kramer65@vps1:~$ rmdir cxs/
rmdir: failed to remove ‘cxs/’: Directory not empty
```

I also tried removing all contents of the dir:

```
kramer65@vps1:~$ cd cxs
kramer65@vps1:~/cxs$ ls
app            README.md
kramer65@vps1:~/cxs$ rm -rf *
kramer65@vps1:~/cxs$ ls
app            README.md
kramer65@vps1:~/cxs$ sudo rm -rf *
kramer65@vps1:~/cxs$ ls
app            README.md
```

I'm okay with failing commands, if only it would tell me whats wrong. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]
I tried the following (also to no avail):

```
kramer65@vps1:~$ sudo rm -vrf cxs/*
removed ‘cxs/app/static/img/face1.jpg’
removed ‘cxs/app/static/img/face2.jpg’
removed ‘cxs/app/static/img/face3.jpg’
[etc.etc.]
removed directory: ‘cxs/app’
removed ‘cxs/README.md’
kramer65@vps1:~$ ls cxs/
app            README.md
kramer65@vps1:~$
```

[EDIT2]
Turns out a colleague had an rsync running which constantly re-wrote the files to that folder. So it did remove them, but it automatically re-created them again as well. (I'm banging my head against the wall here!)

Comment: Have you tried going back a directory and running sudo rm -rf /cxc/*

Comment: @MatthewWilliams - Just tried that, to no avail.. :S

Comment: Try running sudo rm -vf /cxc/* and see what it dumps out

Comment: @MatthewWilliams - I ran it, checkout my updated question.

Comment: At least you know your rsync is working correctly ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
rm -rf /the/full/dir
```

Comment: I tried that, but it again results in a silent fail..

Comment: @kramer65 Are you sure you have the right permissions?

Comment: Well, I'm owner, and I tried using sudo, plus it doesn't say anything about permissions, so I wouldn't know why that would be the problem..

Comment: Try @garethTheRed 's answer. That might work

Comment: Turns out my colleague constantly synced those files from his computer to the server. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: Ha! Yes, such things happen ;) You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Check the extended attributes for the files:

```
lsattr -R /cxs
```

If any have the `i` attribute set then it's immutable, meaning it can't be deleted.

Remove the immutable attribute with:

```
chattr -i <path to file/directory>
```

Then try to delete again.

Note that a file with the immutable attribute set doesn't normally fail silently when you try to delete it but instead complains of 'Operation not permitted'.

Comment: Turns out my colleague constantly synced those files from his computer to the server. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: Colleague!!!??? Go and slap him/her ;-)